# Sorting array of structs by second field in C

Tags: c, qsort

My professor recommended us to use `qsort()` to sort an array of structs. However, I have to come to find out that it is not stable.  I know there are other posts about this topic, but none seem to give an easy fix to stabilize my sort. Is there a way that I could use `qsort()` for a second data field?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Map * collect_values(int n, int *arr);
void sort_values(struct Map *ptr, int n);
void print(struct Map *print_struct, int n);

struct Map{
    int value, position;
};

int compare(const void *aptr, const void *bptr){
    int a = ((struct Map*)aptr)->value, b = ((struct 
Map*)bptr)->value;
return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main(){
    int size, i;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *arr = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    struct Map *p = collect_values(size,arr);
    qsort(p,size,sizeof(struct Map),compare);
    print(p,size);
    free(p);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

struct Map * collect_values(int n, int *arr){
    int i, position = 0;
    struct Map *array = calloc(n,sizeof(*array));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        array[i].value = arr[i];
        array[i].position = position;
        position++;
    }
    return array;

}

void print(struct Map * print_struct, int n){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d : %d\n", print_struct[i].value, 
print_struct[i].position);
    }
}
```

The output now is:

```
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 8
4 : 1
5 : 5
5 : 4
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

How can I maintain the order of the duplicates?  I spent a lot of time trying to figure out `qsort()` and so I'd like to keep it if possible.

**EDIT** I wasn't clear on the output I'm trying to get.  Before sorting, the array of structs contains a value and the index of that value. So, the original array of structs looked like this:

```
 25 : 0
  4 : 1
  3 : 2
 -3 : 3
  5 : 4
  5 : 5
  7 : 6
 88 : 7
  4 : 8
  1 : 9
```

After sorting, my code printed the above. However, what I was hoping for was this:

```
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
4 : 8
5 : 4
5 : 5
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

Where if the values in the first field are equal, then they need to be sorted by values in the second field, which will never be equal because they are the indexes.

Comment: [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is not a stable sort, there's really no good way to bypass that fact. See e.g. [this comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) to find stable sorting algorithms. You have to implement it yourself though (unless you find a library which does it for you).

Comment: You will need to extend your compare function to include the second struct fields.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That doesn't make it [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

Comment: I don't think a stable sort is what you want, but rather you want to sort based on multiple fields: 3-way compare the first fields like a normal qsort comparision. If the fields are equal, return the result of comparing the second fields, otherwise return the result of comparing first fields.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? `qsort` through it's compare, can handle whatever order of a multi-level sort you like, but you have to provide the logic in the *compare* function. As your question sits, other than a vague reference to *"maintain the order of the duplicates"*, it is unclear how you want the output sorted beyond the output you show. (also, in my view, "stable" or not is irrelevant to your question from what I can tell)

Comment: I edited my post to show what output I'm hoping for. I guess I'm not clear on what stable means. I thought it meant that it would maintain the position of the values after sorting.  But I think what I meant was, I would like to sort based on the second field if values of the first field are equal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He asks to sort by second field; he is not searching for a stable algo.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is correct. I put my expected output in the post.

Comment: If the order of e.g. `5 : 4` and `5 : 5` was the opposite, (i.e. `5 : 5` and `5 : 4`) should that order be kept after sorting? Then you want a stable sort which `qsort` can't provide you, otherwise you want to use multiple fields when doing the (unstable) sort.

Comment: Sorry, no. I just want to sort by multiple fields. How can I do that?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That wasn't really clear, and has only been really clarified in the OPs latest comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the struct has a `position` member that represents the initial array ordering, you can easily emulate a stable sort. In the comparison function, if the two `value` members are equal, then return an ordering based on the `position` members, like this:

```
int compare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const struct Map *aptr = ptr1;
    const struct Map *bptr = ptr2;

    if (aptr->value == bptr->value)
        return (aptr->position > bptr->position) - (aptr->position < bptr->position);
    else
        return (aptr->value > bptr->value) - (aptr->value < bptr->value);
}
```

Comment: You know, you're absolutely right. After you stated that I did some research, and even though GNU recommended that technique for mimicking stable-sort with their qsort, what you pointed out makes sense. I'll retract that comment. And thanks for making me think about it.